# Youtube Api with listener for state change

Tags: api, youtube, listener

I'm testing the Youtube API but the state listeners don't work in the demo and I don't understand why?

this is the simple code for the demo:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
                       "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
      ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
      ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    }
    function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
       alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
    }
</script><div id="ytapiplayer">
You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.  </div>
```

Comment: Don't work because I have testing this demo in my local computer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing it on local computer?

Try to test on website and access it with prefix http://

**Edit:** 
You already solved it. Sorry, I realize that after posted.